# What do the Tau battlesuit numbers mean?

Tags: warhammer-40k, tau

Tau battle suits are often dubbed XV88 or XV81, is there a pattern to the number? What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common consensus is that the Battlesuit number is XV (indicating Battlesuit), followed by two digits, constructed based on *size/mass* (1-9, light to heavy) and *function* (1=long-range?, 2=experimental, 4=high-precision(?), 5=stealth, 6=space-faring(?), 8=heavy support), although the functional categories are less clear.

[Lexicanum](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Battlesuit) references [Codex:Tau Empire, 4th Edition, p.35](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Codex%3a_Tau_Empire_%284th_Edition%29), and says:

> Standard nomenclature has these battlesuits categorized by two numbers
>   - the first number denoting which mass class it belongs to, the second its role. For example, in the XV22 Stealth Battlesuit, the first '2'
>   denotes it as a lighter-weight suit, while the second '2' means it is
>   still undergoing field-testing.

The [Warhammer 40K Wiki](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Tau_Battlesuit) has more detail:

> All Tau Battlesuits are essentially the same pieces of Tau technology
>   but can be customized and then given an alphabetical classification
>   code of XV, which is followed by two digits. The first digit indicates
>   the size of the suit: "1" being a complete exoskeletal version of
>   standard Tau body armour, while "8" represents the largest available
>   Battlesuits, the Crisis Battlesuits. The second digit indicates the
>   role or status of the particular suit design. For example: "2"
>   indicates an experimental design, "5" represents a Battlesuit with
>   stealth capability, and "8" denotes a Battlesuit outfitted to provide
>   heavy fire support. Other variations of a Battlesuit may be given
>   different numbers to indicate their functions.

There is also the [XV9](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Hazard_Close_Support_Armour) close combat suit, which has a slightly different naming scheme, and comes in two weapon flavours, the XV9-01 and XV9-04.

Additionally, the 5th edition codex mentions the XV16 and XV26. There is [some speculation](http://www.warseer.com/forums/showthread.php?151313-Strange-Tau-Battle-Suit-numbers-in-the-5ed-book) that the "6" may refer to a new functional designation, possibly space-faring.

Other letters represent different troop types. A detailed (exhaustive?) attempt to summarise them all can be [found here](http://www.advancedtautactica.com/viewtopic.php?t=9399).

Answer (score 1):

It's a tip of the hat to real life military vehicle numbering which uses letters followed by a model number(F18, M1, ext.).  The letter usually represents a type of item: T for tank, F for Fighter, X for experimental, and so on. The number is the sequence of the model.  F-18 is the the 18th fighter model designation used by the US military.*

It may also be a possible reference to a few popular mecha animes.  XV-88 is pretty close to RX-78 the designation of the mecha in the original Gundam series.  This could be a coincidence, but the Tau do borrow some of their visual ascetic from Japanese manga and anime.

I don't think there's a literal meaning for XV other than it sounds cool and follows the pattern.

*This is after the US military reset their designations.  They where getting up into the f-100s.